# Spring 4.3.0.RELEASE - how to send list of objects to jsp by post method?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

- When i try to debug it. i can see that the method from dashboard cntroller isnt called for some reason, any one know how to solve it?

**Updated: addind viewresolver

I dont understad how to user the modelAndView correctley and to use it in my app.

I need that when to userAdmin loged into the site it will direct him to the AdminDeshboard and there all of the users will show in Table or somthing

This is my code:

appconfig-mvc.xml:

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:validation</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value>
        </property>
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean> 


</beans>
```

DashboardController:

```
package com.searcher.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.searcher.entity.UserEntity;
import com.searcher.service.UserService;

@Controller
public class DashboardController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/dashboard")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "<br><div style='text-align:center;'>"
                + "<h3>This message is coming from DashboardController.java </h3></div><br><br>";
        String strEndList = "";

        List<UserEntity> userList = userService.findAll();

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("userList");
        modelAndView.addObject("userList", userList);

        return modelAndView;
        //return new ModelAndView("welcome", "message", message + strEndList);
    }
```

Dashboard.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Dashboard</title>

    <link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
        <form id="logoutForm" method="POST" action="${contextPath}/logout">
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
        </form>

        <h2>Welcome ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} | <a onclick="document.forms['logoutForm'].submit()">Logout</a></h2>


        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>

        <h2>Users:</h2>

        <form action="user.do" method="post">

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Id
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Password
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Email
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Phone
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="user">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            ${user.Id}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ${user.Name}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ${user.Password}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ${user.Email}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ${user.Phone}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>

        </form>


    </c:if>

</div>
<!-- /container -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

appconfig-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/dashboard" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome" authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="name" password-parameter="password"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl">
            <password-encoder ref="encoder"></password-encoder>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl" class="com.searcher.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl"></beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="encoder"
          class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11"/>
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: you are getting any exception/error after sending request to /dashboard?

Comment: @Vaibs No, Something just does not work

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix the issue on how you've called the list from your controller to your JSP.

So, from

```
<c:forEach items="${userList.userList}" var="car">
    <tr>
        <td>
            ${user.Id}
        </td>
        ...
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

to

```
<c:forEach items="${userList}" var="user">
    <tr>
        <td>
            ${user.Id}
        </td>
        ...
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: You're right, I was confused because of tiredness
But this still does not work even after your amendment

Comment: You're expecting to see the result in  `dashboard.jsp` but based from your controller you wanted to view it in `userList.jsp`. `ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("userList");`.

Comment: @Raw Burawes i change it to dashbaord but it still not wotking

Answer (score 0):

Show us please your viewResolver configuration. I think the modelAndView instance is created with a wrong jsp name:

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("userList");
```

and should be:

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("Dashboard");
```